# Android Multiple Flip

Tags: android, animation, flip

I have 9 images that i need to flip either one by one or all at the same time. After being flipped it would show a different image. My problem now is i do not know where to start, i've read some threads here about flipping but most of them only involves on object. I ve also tried a sample from this [tutorial](https://2cupsoftech.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/3d-flip-between-two-view-or-viewgroup-on-android/) but it seem not suitable because it would only pivot in the middle of the screen.

Process:

Its like a reward picker, the screen starts with those 9 tiles faced up with rewards description(text) and after that it would faced down like the one on the screenshot. And all tiles will move to the center and back to position after being randomized. And then the user would chose a card for the reward.

Process:

[image]
Here is the Image:

[image: 9 card Flip]

Here is my xml code for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="40dp"
android:weightSum="3" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction on where to start? I ve also read from the android dev site but it is using two  whole fragment for flipping.

Comment: Can you please give more detail? What will the screen look like to start? What will the user do? What happens after the user's action? What will the screen look like at the end?

Comment: Its like a reward picker, the screen starts with those 9 tiles faced  up with rewards description(text) and after that it would faced down like the one on the screenshot.  And all tiles will move to the center and back to position after being randomized. And then the user would chose a card for the reward.

Comment: Can you post some mocked screens to help us understand better what you want to do?